# Transformation of time series into and from images using recurrence plots

Tags: time-series, python

It is possible to transform time series into images (recurrence plots) as shown [here](https://www.kaggle.com/tigurius/recuplots-and-cnns-for-time-series-classification). However, I wonder if it's possible to transform a recurrence plot back to time series?

In particular, I need to determine the ranges of time series that the red-colored area (see image below) refers to. Is it possible to estimate? For example, light color may refer to a peak in time series or something similar...

Any comment and recommendation will be highly evaluated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The transformation is not invertible, because it involves a Procrustean truncation (via the Heaviside function).  The idea is to *strip off* a great deal of the information in the data in order to see potentially recurring patterns.

Comment: Ok, thanks, @whuber.